# Getting libusb error in ubuntu while trying to run 2 Kinects

Tags: ubuntu, usb, kinect, libusb, openkinect

I'm trying to run two Kinects v2 on the same machine (using libfreenect2 for ubuntu 14.04). The one is connected to motherboard USB3 host, and the other to PCI-E NEC host. Both work fine separately, but if I run one and then run another while the first is running, I get the following error for the second kinect:

```
[Error] [protocol::CommandTransaction] bulk transfer failed! libusb error -1: LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
```

I know that it is possible to run multiple kinects on the same machine, but can't figure out what causes this error. I also tried some other hosts that didn't help. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem: need to allocate bigger memory buffer to usbfx, and don't do that using

```
sudo modprobe usbcore usbfs_memory_mb=64
```

Rather better do it by correcting the grub file (more here: https://www.ptgrey.com/tan/10685).